# wrapInner() alternative

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to add a new div that will wrap around some content on my site. I can get it to work with wrapInner but that will not work in my case because the content I am wrapping has 2 scripts (facebook and youtube) included. Those two scripts end up running twice and they end up on the page in two different locations. (I guess this is a known issue with wrapInner.)

The page is part of a hosted solution in a Saas environment. I have very limited access to the page code. The page is loading jQuery v1.3.2 and I don't have access to the head section so I cannot change that to a newer version. I also cannot change the facebook or youTube scripts, they are hardcoded and not accessible. My script has to run within the body tags. I can add PHP if that helps anyone come up with a solution.

Here's my page layout:

```
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="detail">
    ...additional content...
    <facebok script>
    <youtube script>
    ...additional content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I want:

```
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="detail">      
    <div id="my_New_Div">         <-- New div starts here
      ...additional content...
      <facebok script>
      <youtube script>
      ...additional content...
    </div>                        <-- New div ends here 
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the script I am using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // add an extra div for design
   $('.content-main .detail').wrapInner('<div class="detail-inside"></div>');
 </script>
```

Comment: I believe the Facebook and Youtube scripts are run once when the page is initially loaded and then run again when wrapInner is called?

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

This should work as of Jquery 1.0

```
var content = $('.content').html();
$('.content').empty().html('<div class="my_New_Div">' + content + '</div>');
```

or as a plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.wrapInner2=function(wrapWith){
        return this.each(function(){
            var c = $(wrapWith).append($(this).html());
            $(this).empty().append(c);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Didn't work. Ends up with and empty div and no new div.

    <div class="detail"></div>

(Also- I think you need a pair double quotes ("") instead of the single quote (') around id="my_New_Div" )

Comment: NM previous comment. I made an error. It DOES work, however it causes the same problem- the inner scripts run twice.

Comment: maybe create a true/false variable, check inside the facebook/youtube scripts if it's true/false and only run when it's false, then set to true after it's finished?

Comment: Sorry Pastor, that's way over my head man. But I think you're on the right track. Maybe I can delay the facebook and youtube scripts until after the new div has been inserted? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a WORKAROUND.**

I noticed that the positioning of my jQuery script within the page affected the output in the html. Specifically, one set of the facebook and youTube instances would show up where they were originally called in the page (the correct positions for my design) and the other (unwanted) set would show up wherever I placed my jQuery script.

So my workaround is to place my script inside a div that has a style of display:none. This is working.

I'd still like to find a better solution of not having the inner scripts repeat themselves so I will leave this question open.